# Jupyter notebook kernels do not launch in notebook's directory

Tags: linux, directory, jupyter-notebook

I run:

- Jupyter 4.2.0
- notebook 4.2.3
- Linux Mint 18

The notebook application starts correctly and in the correct directory. But when I open a notebook, the python kernel is launched in `~/user` and not in the notebooks directory (as it used to be). This problems seems to be happening since I encrypted my home folder.

Could this be a permission issue ?

Comment: The code to calculate that path is [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/4c54f598ac73c4992a663c21e16d36b629b8098e/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py#L502) and [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/4c54f598ac73c4992a663c21e16d36b629b8098e/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py#L61). Can you try `os.path.isdir('/path/to/foo')` on the directory it should be starting in?

Comment: `os.path.isdir(/path/to/notebook/directory)`returns `True`.

Comment: That's weird. If you can still reproduce it, can you open an issue [on jupyter/notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues) about this?